# Having trouble navigating to other pages in my website after adding in jquery scroll functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a website for a small company. On a particular page of the website, I made it so that when you click on a title in the table of contents, it scrolls down to that section of the page.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!-- The title of the Problem Section in the Table of Contents-->
    <a href="#problem">Problem</a>
    <!-- Section of Page Titled Problem-->
    <h2 id="problem">Problem</h2>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
    $("nav").find("a").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var section = $(this).attr("href");
             $("html, body").animate({
             scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
                });
             })
```

When I click on problem in the table of contents, the url becomes demo.com/home.html#problem.

This works just fine. It scrolls down to that section of the page when I click on the title in the table of contents.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to navigate to another page in the website (i.e. contact.html, etc) via the navigation bar, I'm not able to.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault()`. That's whats preventing the page transfer on click

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used `e.preventDefault()` in JS which prevents anchor's default behaviour i.e. redirection. So give a class/id to problem anchor and use it in js that will be a better option

Answer (score 1):

For the link action to work you need to remove the `e.preventDefault()` call:

```
$("nav").find("a").click(function() {
  var section = $(this).attr("href");
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
  });
})
```